# Typescript handbook generic type question

Tags: typescript

Hi I am following the https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html and saw the following function

```
function loggingIdentity<T>(arg: T[]): T[] {
  console.log(arg.length);
  return arg;
}
```

Below is the explanation:

*You can read the type of loggingIdentity as “the generic function loggingIdentity takes a type parameter T, and an argument arg which is an array of Ts, and returns an array of Ts.” If we passed in an array of numbers, we’d get an array of numbers back out, as T would bind to number. This allows us to use our generic type variable T as part of the types we’re working with, rather than the whole type, giving us greater flexibility.*

I am trying to understand why is there a need to declare a `<T>` in the function. I understood that the function now takes an array of a generic type and return a value with that generic type as well. Why can't we just remove the redundancy and declare as follows:

```
function loggingIdentity(arg: T[]): T[] {
  console.log(arg.length);
  return arg;
}
```

Comment: How would the TS compiler know what T is in this case ? Should it assume that any type identifier that doesn't exist is a template identifier ? I'm not sure that's better than the explicit declaration. Also, this way allows you to impose constraints on the template types.

Comment: As intimated by @AdrianBuzea, this simply wouldn't work without massive language changes. If it did work, it would introduce an absolutely massive potential for bugs because any types that have not been imported or are not correctly declared would be inferred as implicit generic parameter declarations. Given that generic types only become verbose when they are constrained, and an implicit declaration would not be constrained, it would also be fairly useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `<T>` in the function, you declare that `T` is a generic parameter. If you don't do that, Typescript doesn't know what `T` means in `arg: T[]`. It would simply think that you misspelled a type name.